# Malformed security header

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, server, reboot

After installing Ubuntu I shut down my laptop. When I restarted it I got this error message:

```
Malformed security header
Failed to read header: Invalid Parameter
Failed to load images: Invalid Parameter
start_img() returned Invalid Parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert Ubuntu from UEFI mode into Legacy mode.

Use this procedure only to convert an UEFI mode Ubuntu installation to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Such a conversion may be necessary if some hardware doesn't work correctly under UEFI mode. (Graphics cards are a common source of problems.) Converting to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode while Windows boots in UEFI mode can make the boot process more awkward -- you'll need to use the computer's built-in boot manager to switch between OSs, and some computer's have such poor boot managers that this may be impossible.

- If Ubuntu is installed on a GPT disk (you can check it via the `sudo parted -l` command), use GParted partition editor to create a BIOS-Boot partition (1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag) at the start of its disk.
- Start [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), and select *Advanced options* -> *GRUB location* tab.
- Uncheck the *Separate /boot/efi partition* option

  [image: Uncheck the Separate /boot/efi partition option]
- Click the *Apply* button in the lower right corner.
- Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in Legacy mode. Generally this setting is located in the *Boot* tab → *Boot order* section of the BIOS.

<sub>**Source:** revised from: [UEFI - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_or_Legacy_mode)</sub>